# Will you die or suffer bad luck because of watching mermaid?

Tags: allah

I watched a video where real mermaid got caught. I heard that if you see a mermaid you will die or suffer from bad luck.Is there any Islamic definition regarding this issue? Will it harm you... please respnse...

Comment: "luck" is something unislamic.

Comment: mermaid is something culturally made up and is a fairytale, it doesn't exist in islam

Answer (score 1):

LAW THIYARAH (TATHAYYUR, CONSIDERING BAD FOR SOMETHING) [1] By Al-Ustadz Yazid bin Abdul Qodir Jawas Ahlus Sunnah does not believe in the Thiyarah or Tathayyur. Tathayyur or thiyarah is feeling bad luck because of something [2]. Taken from the sentence: زَجَرَ الطَّيْرَ (flying birds). Ibnul Qayyim (died 751 H) rahimahullah said: "In the past, they like to fly or release birds, if they fly to the right, then they call them 'saa-ih', if they fly to the left, they call them ' baarih '. If the flight is called ‘na-thih’, ​​and when it is backward, they call it ‘qa-id’. Some Arabs consider bad luck with 'baarih' (the bird flies to the left) and consider luck with 'saa-ih' (the bird flies to the right) and there are others who think otherwise. " [3] Tathayyur (feeling unlucky) is not limited to the flight of birds, but to the names, numbers, numbers, handicapped people and the like. All that is forbidden in Islamic shari'ah and included in the category of shirk by the Prophet sallallaahu ‘alayhi wa sallam, because people who believe that these things bring benefits and harm. Such beliefs clearly violate the belief in taqdir (provisions) of Allah Azza wa Jalla.